# Ordenar consulta MYSQL con AS o AND

Tags: mysql

Disculpen alguien tiene idea de como ordenar el total de menor a mayor utilizando su alias o con un AND, cuando lo agrego en GROUP BY total no me obtiene ningún resultado, alguien podria ayudarme.

este es mi consulta actual.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%W %d %M %Y') AS fecha,

    IFNULL (COUNT(t.id),0) AS total,

    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM calendar.datefield) AS mes

    FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t 

    RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(t.date_created) = calendar.datefield)

    WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(date_created)) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets)

    AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(date_created)) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets))

    AND month(calendar.datefield) = 12 AND year(calendar.datefield) = 2022

    GROUP BY fecha DESC LIMIT 10
```

y me devuelve esto pero yo quiero ordenarlo por el total

| fecha | total | mes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wednesday 28 December 2022 | 2 | 12 |
| Wednesday 21 December 2022 | 0 | 12 |
| Wednesday 14 December 2022 | 7 | 12 |
| Wednesday 07 December 2022 | 3 | 12 |
| Tuesday 27 December 2022 | 1 | 12 |
| Tuesday 20 December 2022 | 3 | 12 |
| Tuesday 13 December 2022 | 5 | 12 |
| Tuesday 06 December 2022 | 5 | 12 |
| Thursday 29 December 2022 | 2 | 12 |
| Thursday 22 December 2022 | 3 | 12 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from
(
 SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%W %d %M %Y') AS fecha,
  IFNULL (COUNT(t.id),0) AS total,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM calendar.datefield) AS mes
 FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t 
 RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(t.date_created) = calendar.datefield)
 WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(date_created)) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets)
 AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(date_created)) FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets))
 AND month(calendar.datefield) = 12 AND year(calendar.datefield) = 2022
 GROUP BY fecha DESC LIMIT 10
) T
order by t.Total;
```

Sobre tu consulta original aplicas otra consulta y entonces ordenas por el total previamente calculado en tu consulta original.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, solo que el order by t.Total; es order by total , pero fuera de es todo bien muchas gracias broo...